# Vuetify Error: Property or method N is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create a component with a list of cards but it always throws an error:

Property or method "ac" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

I have check code looks like to be valid, but the error come every time. I have googled but unfortunately it did not help. Appreciate any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
      <vutify-main></vutify-main>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>

    Vue.component('vutify-main', {
        template: `
        <v-app>
            <v-main>
                <v-btn @click="show">test</v-btn>
                <accounts-list
                    :overlay="accountListOverlay"
                    :accounts="accountList"
                ></accounts-list> 
            </v-main>
        </v-app>
        `,
        data: function() {
            return {
                accountListOverlay: false,
                accountList: [{ "account_id": 1, "account_name": "1", "account_url": "1" }]
            };
        },
        methods: {
            show: function() {
                return this.accountListOverlay = !this.accountListOverlay;
            }
        }

    });
    
Vue.component('accounts-list', {
    template: `
    <v-overlay :value="overlay">
        <v-list color="transparent">
            <v-card v-for="ac in accounts" :key="ac.account_id" light style="margin-bottom: 10px;>
                <div>
                    <v-card-title class="font-weight-regular">Account Name:</v-card-title>
                    <v-card-subtitle class="font-weight-light body-1">
                        {{ ac.account_url }} - {{ ac.account_id }}
                    </v-card-subtitle>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <v-card-title class="font-weight-regular">Description:</v-card-title>
                    <v-card-subtitle class="font-weight-light body-1">
                        {{ ac.account_name }}
                    </v-card-subtitle>
                </div>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-btn
                        text color="#7ec3d8"
                        rounded
                        text
                    >Get data
                    </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-list>
    </v-overlay>
    `,
    props: {
        overlay: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
            default: false
        },
        accounts: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            default: []
        }
    },
});

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify()
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible that it's because you're missing a closing quote in the style tag in this line `<v-card v-for="ac in accounts" :key="ac.account_id" light style="margin-bottom: 10px;>`?

Comment: @criticalsession oh damn, yeah, thank you!